# wpf content transition

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, transition

I have a usercontrol in WPF that have 2 buttons inside.
The buttons are in overlay, you only see one button at a time.
And i want to use a fade transition between buttons.

I can accomplish this with an opacity animation in codebehind with this layout:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="buttonA">A</Button>
        <Button x:Name="buttonB">B</Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But i want a better solution, preferably in XAML.
Something like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <TransitionContent CurrentContent="{Binding CurrentItemKey}" Transition="Fade">

        <TransitionContentItem Key="ItemA">
            <Button x:Name="buttonA">A</Button>
        </TransitionContentItem>

        <TransitionContentItem Key="ItemB">
            <Button x:Name="buttonB">B</Button>
        </TransitionContentItem>

    </TransitionContent>
</UserControl>
```

Can i use LayoutToolkit:TransitioningContentControl to accomplish this?

What other options are there?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether or not you will accept this as an answer but here goes:

Transitioning from a button to a button probably means that you should have a single button with (at least) two states.

If you use The [VisualStateManager](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-visual-state-manager-overview.aspx) to define the states and manage them you'll get the transitions thrown in.

**EDIT** in response to your comment:

You might subclass and style a tabcontrol. As soon as another tab page is made active you animate its opacity. That way you could create a generic transitioning container.

**EDIT** Found an [interesting project on codeplex](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Sorry for my bad example; change the two buttons for two ContentControls.

Comment: Great idea, i can do it with a custom tabControl or selector.

Comment: Thanks Erno, here are a faded tabControl:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247954/fade-between-tab-pages-in-a-tab-control

Comment: @eze1981, the link you added in comment is NOT a WPF solution.